# Win7 x64 IE10 "Open in new Tab" results in blank page

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet-explorer-10

OK, one of my users has a very perplexing issue. When you middle click on any link, in any website, or if a website tries to open a new window (that opens in a new tab) the user is presented with a blank tab. IE10 will not load any page in that tab, unless you type the URL manually, then suddenly it's fine.

Win 7 SP1 x64 with all patches
Brand new computer

1. It's not an addon - running without addons does not improve the saturation
2. It's not a corruption with the user profile, it happens with the other profiles on that PC
3. It's not a setting in IE10 that gets reset with "Reset all IE10 settings"
4. It's not a corrupt file that gets checked with SFC or when I remove and then re-install IE10 from Add Remove Programs (Windows components)
5. It's not the pop-up blocker
6. It's not SmartScreen
7. It's not Flash or Java
8. I very very much doubt it's the A/V - there's no IE plugin and there are dozens of clients running the same A/V
9. It's not compatibility mode (happens with or without it)
10. It's not an individual site, it can be reproduced on every site.
11. It isn't improved when I change that registry key that defines if a Tab opens as a Thread or a Process

Has anyone got any ideas of what it is??

Dom

Comment: FYI, this computer is still suffering this fault. User was moved to FF back when the fault could not be rectified. I'm going to assume IE11 will eventually fix this user's problem, because short of a complete re-image I cannot see a way of repairing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registering `ieproxy.dll` fixed the problem for me, run:

`regsvr32 "c:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\ieproxy.dll"`

Source: 
["New Tab" freezes opening link in 32-bit Explorer on 64-bit Windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/92073/new-tab-freezes-opening-link-in-32-bit-explorer-on-64-bit-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: THANKYOU! Fixed customer's IE10 - working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

### Method 1

1. Open Registry Editor by typing `regedit` in Start Menu search box or press <kbd>[image]</kbd> + `R` and type `regedit`.
2. Navigate to: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet\Explorer\Main`.
3. Create a DWORD value, and name it `TabProcGrowt`.
4. Set it to `1` and after restarting IE.

`TabProcGrowth = 0`: Tabs will be created as threads(instead 
of processes) in the iexplore.exe process(only 1 process exist, thus no save 
path resets).

`TabProcGrowth = 1`: Tabs will be created as separate 
sub-processes according to different mandatory integrity 
levels.

`TabProcGrowth > 1`: Tabs will be created as separate 
sub-processes until the maximum number of tabs(specified by this value) is 
reached.

`No TabProcGrowth value`: Default, amount of free physical memory 
will determine the number of sub-processes.

### Method 2

Using the tool [Complete Internet Repair](http://datumza.com/downloads/).

> Tool that will help you to reset the Winsock configuration to default
>   or clean state. It will help if you are having any of the following
>   problems like internet or network problem after removing adware,
>   spyware, virus, worm, Trojan horse, loss network connection after
>   installing/uninstalling adware, spyware, antispam, vpn, firewall or
>   other networking programs, unable to access any webpage or can only
>   access some webpages, pop-up error window with network related problem
>   description, no network connectivity due to registry errors, and DNS
>   lookup problem.

[image]

**Warning**: After the application runs it will force you to reboot and close any and all apps or windows. All of your troubles will be over BUT the reboot is not a request. SAVE any projects that are open because the system will REBOOT.

Comment: Never used this Complete Internet Repair, but since cNet is crap and known for distributing malware here's the author's site with both 32 and 64-bit versions: http://datumza.com/downloads/

Comment: I already said "It isn't improved when I change that registry key that defines if a Tab opens as a Thread or a Process". Also, the only script in that tool that might help is Repair Internet Explorer. All the other features of windows described in that tool are functioning correctly.

Answer (score -1):

YES,
after long searching , and trying almost everything on the WEB, it was only method one which solved my Issue :

WIN 7
Explorer 9 then updated to 11
links are always blocked or opening blank page

I couldn't donwload the fixing utilities because it is company computer and I cannot install external files. but I got permission to try the dward in method 1 and it works.

thank you all

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.